# Extracting file paths using substring

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2012, substring, charindex

I am trying to extract the file name(which has been successful) and then each filepath destination in its own column.

Example file path: mps://Global/Test/Health/Reports/file.html

Expected Result (in four separate columns):

```
File.html Reports Health Test Global
```

My actual result (only two columns):

```
File.html mps://Global/Test/Health/Reports
```

My query:

```
select 
RIGHT(filepath, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(filepath)) -1) AS ReportName
LEFT(filepath,LEN(filepath) - charindex('/',reverse(filepath),1) + 1) AS ReportPath,
from LOG;
```

I'm been trying to figure out how I can extract each path between each '/' in their own respective columns. I've experimented with many charindex changes for the four separate columns but am having trouble getting rid of the left and right side of the string. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this need to be dynamic? Could the path be longer like `//global/test/health/somemore/somemore/somemore/somemore/file.html`?

Comment: yes it can be but i just put a shorter example because I just want to go four sections back

Comment: Ok so for clarification. You only want 4 sections even if it were to go say 10?

Comment: yes but the max is 6 from looking at the largest column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning it into XML then target the "nodes";

```
declare @yak varchar(100) = 'mps://Global/Test/Health/Reports/file.html';

declare @x xml = cast('<r><i>' + replace(replace(@yak, 'mps://', ''), '/', '</i><i>') + '</i></r>' as xml);

select  [Col1] = r.n.value('i[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        [Col2] = r.n.value('i[2]', 'varchar(100)'),
        [Col3] = r.n.value('i[3]', 'varchar(100)'),
        [Col4] = r.n.value('i[4]', 'varchar(100)'),
        [Col5] = r.n.value('i[5]', 'varchar(100)'),
        [Col6] = r.n.value('i[6]', 'varchar(100)')
from    @x.nodes('r')r(n);
```

Returns:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5        Col6
----    ----    ----    ----    ----        ----
Global  Test    Health  Reports file.html   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want the [string_split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) function.  ISTR a function specifically to parse filenames into 4 parts (drive, directory, base, extension) but maybe that's in the C runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use case when inside of the charindex, especially if some of the filepaths are left null.